# dplyr arrange is not working while order is fine

Tags: r

I am trying to obtain the largest 10 investors in a country but obtain confusing result using arrange in dplyr versus order in base R.

```
head(fdi_partner)
```

give the following results

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `Main counterparts` `Number of projects` `Total registered capital (Mill. USD)(*)`
  <chr>               <chr>                <chr>                                    
1 TOTAL               1818                 38854.3                                  
2 Singapore           231                  11358.66                                 
3 Korea Rep.of        377                  7679.9                                   
4 Japan               204                  4325.79                                  
5 Netherlands         24                   4209.64                                  
6 China, PR           216                  3001.79
```

and

```
fdi_partner %>% 
    rename("Registered capital" = "Total registered capital (Mill. USD)(*)")  %>%
    mutate_at(c("Number of projects", "Registered capital"), as.numeric) %>%
    arrange("Number of projects") %>% 
  head()
```

give almost the same result

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `Main counterparts` `Number of projects` `Registered capital`
  <chr>                              <dbl>                <dbl>
1 TOTAL                               1818               38854.
2 Singapore                            231               11359.
3 Korea Rep.of                         377                7680.
4 Japan                                204                4326.
5 Netherlands                           24                4210.
6 China, PR                            216                3002.
```

while the following code is working fine with base R

```
head(fdi_partner)
fdi_numeric <- fdi_partner %>% 
    rename("Registered capital" = "Total registered capital (Mill. USD)(*)")  %>%
    mutate_at(c("Number of projects", "Registered capital"), as.numeric)  

head(fdi_numeric[order(fdi_numeric$"Number of projects", decreasing = TRUE), ], n=11)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   `Main counterparts`   `Number of projects` `Registered capital`
   <chr>                                <dbl>                <dbl>
 1 TOTAL                                 1818               38854.
 2 Korea Rep.of                           377                7680.
 3 Singapore                              231               11359.
 4 China, PR                              216                3002.
 5 Japan                                  204                4326.
 6 Hong Kong SAR (China)                  132                2365.
 7 United States                           83                 783.
 8 Taiwan                                  66                1464.
 9 United Kingdom                          50                 331.
10 F.R Germany                             37                 131.
11 Thailand                                36                 370.
```

Can anybody help explain what's wrong with me?

Comment: Try `arrange(df, -``Number of projects``)`, with one backtick instead of 2.

Comment: Like @bretauv said! (how did you do that?)

Comment: @Edward use 3 backticks at the beginning and at the end (like when you put a code block)

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` (and more generally `tidyverse` packages) accept only unquoted variable names. If your variable name has a space in it, you must wrap it in backticks:

```r
library(dplyr)

test <- data.frame(`My variable` = c(3, 1, 2), var2 = c(1, 1, 1), check.names = FALSE)
test
#>   My variable var2
#> 1           3    1
#> 2           1    1
#> 3           2    1

# Your code (doesn't work)
test %>%
  arrange("My variable")
#>   My variable var2
#> 1           3    1
#> 2           1    1
#> 3           2    1

# Solution
test %>%
  arrange(`My variable`)
#>   My variable var2
#> 1           1    1
#> 2           2    1
#> 3           3    1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: And put a dash (-) in front to sort in descending order. ;)